# Can Black Holes be the Dark Matter?

Tags: gravity, black-holes

Seems to fit the definition: interacts with gravity, doesn’t radiate energy (except Hawking Radiation) and could create gravity lensing without absorbing very much of the light.

Could 80% of the original matter created in the Big Bang have ended up in lots of black holes thereby giving us the amount of mass to balance the universes gravity?

Kent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is impossible for several reasons.

- Each black holes would have to be insanely massive.

A black hole the size of a proton (which Hawking radiates pions like crazy) already has the mass of a mountain. The radius and mass of a black hole are proportional, and at 1 Planck length of 10^{-34} m, it has 10^{-5} g of mass. At 10^{-15}m, you have 10^11 Kg. But this is nonsense, the black holes would have to be bigger than the wavelength of visible light at least, to avoid Hawking radiating visible light, which is another factor of 10^8, which means that each one would have the mass of 10^{20} Kg, the mass of a small celestial body. They would clump matter around them gravitationally, and you couldn't miss them.

- Black holes are not weakly interacting

Such massive black holes have strong gravitational scattering of other objects, they don't pass right through. It is implausible that they would form spherical clouds around galaxies, they would have strong scattering and friction with galactic gas and dust, and they would end up in the galactic disk along with everything else.

- Black holes explode

The few black holes which are small enough to decay would lead to signature Hawking explosions at the end stages, which were searched for and not found.

- Black holes can't be the end-product of inflation

When you have an inflating universe, the end of inflation is gravitationally homogenous for good reason--- it is coming from the maximum entropy state, the deSitter state, of a positive cosmological constant universe. Any black holes will be diluted by inflation, which can be viewed as the black hole falling into the cosmological horizon. When inflation ends, the end is graceful and not sufficiently inhomogenous to clump matter into black holes, at least not until after some time has passed for the matter to clump in the ordinary way.

Comment: There have been speculations on string models with some large (mm) dimensions where black holes appear and are sought for through their thermodynamic decay to many particles at the LHC. This might imply that a model might be found where a stable mini black hole of TeV mass might be concocted ( reviving the scare for the LHC). Alternatively it could be called a stable solution of a quantum gravitational equation (no Hawking radiation). There are more things....

Comment: @anna v: I consider large extra dimensions to be a form of scientific fraud. There is no reason to take such ideas seriously, they are already ruled out, and were ruled out before they were first proposed. As for stable black holes, If a black hole is stable, it is not a black hole, by definition, it is a particle.

Comment: Ron, you've said this before about Large Extra Dimensions - would you care to elaborate (are you grouping RS with ADD in this?)? Thanks.
Out of interest, how much faith do you personally think we should put in Hawking radiation?

Comment: @James: This is because there is no mechanism for suppressing non-renormalizable terms, but people say there is despite the fact that none of the mechanisms work well. Majorana neutrino mass comes from two Higgs/two lepton doublet nonrenormalizable dimension 5 term, and it tells you immediately that the scale of non-renormalizability is about 10^16 GeV. In order to reproduce this (RS or ADD) you need to suppress order after order by hand using additional symmetries. This by itself is absurd fine tuning. People said only right handed neutrino gives neutrino mass, but this is just plain wrong.

Comment: But this is not enough. After you deal with neutrino masses, you need to deal with proton decay. Arkani Hamed and Schmaltz gave a method of suppressing proton decay, by placing quarks and leptons on different branes. This works, but it requires that the SU(2) U(1) gauge fields be delocalized to hit both the quarks and the leptons, and this means that U(1) and SU(2) coupling is suppressed by large dimensions, just like gravity. This means that the electroweak couplings have to start blowing up at around a TeV like crazy, which there is no hint of experimentally.

Comment: Finally, there are additional non-renormalizable corrections: strong CP is violated by nearly all of these, the electroweak breaking is modified by these, so that there are nonrenormalizable Z and W interactions which do not follow from the standard model, you could easily get nonrenormalizable effects which wreck muon magnetic moment, all of these terms have to be suppressed by hand, order by order. Nobody does this, because if you do, it becomes obvious that this is a phony made up model. Kakushadze used to do this suppression order by order, and he got heckled and left physics.

Comment: @James: RS is only interesting because warped compactification is not restricted to large extra dimensions. If the Planck scale is kept at the traditional value, you can still put branes in the compactification, and this is what people were getting excited about. But the good models are not RS models, but those of Kachru and collaborators, which do not make any large-extra dimensions assumptions. Large extra dimensions has been useful only in getting to take extra dimension physics seriously, although classical compactification and local hidden symmetry should have been enough.

Comment: @James: Hawking radiation is 100% firmly established, it is as certain as any phenomenon that has not been experimentally observed can be. The paradoxes related to Hawking radiation have been understood thoroughly, and there is really no room for modification of the basic idea, especially since string theory reproduces the Area-entropy law quantitatively for extremal black holes, and qualitatively for the rest.

Comment: This seems like an interesting analogue http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2010/09/hawking-radiation-in-the-lab/ , at least mathematically?

Comment: @anna v: That looks like fantastic work--- there were people looking for good analogs since forever, in sound waves in fluids, and so on, but is seems from the wired article that these guys not only found a realizable analog, but found _optical_ hawking radiation. It is important to make sure this is really thermal radiation (or can be considered as such) from a horizon, but I am amazed. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Could I go back to your comment about celestial-mass black holes being readily observable. Would this really the case? I mean an even distribution of black holes wouldn't cause clumping of stars distinct from the observed distribution of stars in the galaxy, would it? (Ignoring issues with how we actually observe DM to be distributed)

Comment: @James: the issue is that you would be able to distinguish _individual_ black holes with their individual clumping clouds. It wouldn't look like a homogeneous matter density. The point is that the black holes would be so massive that their gravitational dynamics would be the opposite of that of WIMPS, it would be formidable particle by particle.

Comment: I'm sure you're correct, but I don't understand the objections you raise. Up until about ~10 years ago it was seriously considered that black holes, or other massive compact objects *could* (partially) explain dark matter.There could be (hypothetically) lots of stellar sized black holes floating around out there, just as there are probably a billion neutron stars in our Galaxy. We don't see most of these neutron stars and unless they are in binary systems they go unnoticed. Matter doesn't "clump" around stars and it wouldn't clump around stellar-sized black holes.

Comment: Ditto for the weak-interaction objection. Stars in the Galaxy don't really interact with each other. Stellar-sizedblack holes, or even black holes bigger than the mass of the Earth won't explode. I think the objections are that we know of no way to produce them and the observations of microlensing towards the Magellanic clouds and the Galactic centre rule them out.

Comment: @RobJeffries: Ok, I didn't consider black holes so big--- I imagined lots of proton sized black holes. I agree with most of your comments, I haven't thought about this.